# A add/subtract function that rotates numbers from 1 to 12

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm having difficulty searching for this since I don't know what it's called. I want a function which will add/subtract in a circular fashion from 1 to 12. I could do this with logic operators (if output>12 then subtract 12 etc), but I want to see if it can be done without logic operators. Something on the lines of the following use cases:

```
Format: add(num1, num2)
        sub(num1, num2)

add(1, 4) = 5 // Straightforward
add(9, 5) = 2 // 14 > 12 so return 14-12
sub(3, 9) = 6 // -6 < 0  so return 12-6
```

I hope this is clear. The use case for this is I'm writing a database query which will automatically take the timestamp and return the last 4 months from it. The DB I'm using is proprietary and doesn't have very powerful date processing functions.

EDIT: Perfect! Thanks to Turkeyhundt's answer, the way I got this is as follows:

```
(60 + x) % 12
```

The `mod` operator on my system returns negative remainders, so I put in the 60 to convert it to always positive. So it will work properly for 5 years!

Comment: Are you familiar with modular addition?

Comment: DOH! So simple - I don't know why it never came to me, it's been years since I learnt about it! Thanks so much! If you would answer the question, I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think modular addition would accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you want to use modular arithmetic. Heres a wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic, but I'll give you a quick rundown.

If I wanted to count from one to 10 in modulo 5. I only have 5 digits I can use, thats {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}. So counting to 10 would go something like:

$$ 0 \rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 0 $$

So 10mod5 is 0. This is also sometimes called clock arithmetic. From the sounds of things, you're programming this into a computer, therefore you can use the modulo operator in most programming languages (c, python etc..), the symbol is just (%).

So you can usually calculate 10mod5 in a computer by using

$$ 10 \% 5 = 0 $$

So to answer your question, if you wanted to add two numbers $a$ and $b$ with modular arithmetic just use:

$$ sum = (a+b)\%12 $$

This will give you numbers from 0-11 as discussed. If you want 1-12, just add 1:

$$ sum = (a+b)\%12 +1 $$